# How to filter distinct values of a column in SparkR

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe (df_view) read into SparkR with columns : orderID and item.
How can select all distinct IDs ?
The query : result <- SparkR::sql("select DISTINCT ID from df_view") is throwing errors

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: ERROR RBackendHandler: sql on 1 failed
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException....

Comment: Error in handleErrors(returnStatus, conn) : 
  org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`Order`' given input columns: [df_view.

Comment: seems like the problem is in your syntax rather than the query itself